# Is there a way to partially control the order of a Java parallel stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I understand that it doesn't make sense to attempt to make a parallel stream execute each element in a specific order. Since it runs the data in parallel, there will clearly be some non-determinism in the ordering. However, I was wondering if it's possible to make it execute "sort of" in order, or at least attempt to keep the ordering somewhat similar to what it would be if it were sequential.

## Use case

I am need to execute some code on every combination of values from a few arrays. I create a stream of all of the possible index combinations as follows (names of variables have been obfuscated in order to not reveal proprietary information, I promise I don't normally name my variables `arr1`, `arr2` etc.):

```
public static void doMyComputation(double[] arr1, double[] arr2, double[] arr3) {
  DoubleStream.of(arr1).mapToObj(Double::valueOf)
    .flatMap(
      i1->DoubleStream.of(arr2).mapToObj(Double::valueOf)
        .flatMap(
          i2->DoubleStream.of(arr3).mapToObj(Double::valueOf)
            .flatMap(
              i3->new Inputs(i1,i2,i3)
             )
        )
    )
    .parallel()
    .forEach(input -> doComputationallyIntensiveThing(input.i1, input.i2, input.i3);
```

This works fine (or at least the real version does, I simplified some things for the code snipped I posted here, so it's possible I messed the code snippet up). I expect that due to parallelism, I'm not going to see the values in the order `arr1[0], arr2[0], arr3[0]`, followed by `arr1[0], arr2[0], arr3[1]`, etc. However, I was hoping that I would at least mostly see inputs with the first few values from `arr1` first, and then slowly work my way to the end of `arr1`. I was surprised to see that it didn't even come close to that.

The problem is that in that `doComputationallyIntensiveThing` method, there is some caching that only behaves well if we see many of the same values from `arr1` together. If the values are fed in completely randomly, then the caching causes more harm than good.

Is there any way to hint at the stream to execute the inputs in an order that tends to group the inputs together by the values in `arr1`?

If there's not, then I can probably just make a new stream for each value in `arr1` and it will work out ok, but I'd like to see if there's a way to do this all in one stream.

Comment: Probably not.  Streams are designed to make _simple_ cases of parallelization simple, and not really intended to do anything more sophisticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you should not assume a particular processing order for parallel streams, but assuming that your algorithm is correct, regardless of the actual processing order, you can reason about the relationship between order and performance.

The Stream implementation *is* already designed to allow to benefit from processing consecutive elements—for a local processor. So when you have a Stream of hundred elements, say `IntStream.range(0, 100)` for simplification, and process it with four otherwise idle CPU cores, the implementation will split it into the four ranges 0-25, 25-50, 50-75, and 75-100, to be processed independently, in the best case. So each processor will process consecutive elements locally and benefit from lowlevel effects, e.g. fetching multiple array elements into its local cache at once, etc.

So the problem with your `doComputationallyIntensiveThing` method seems to be, that the cache (and your monitoring) is not working locally. So, to stay with the example above, the operation would start with parallel executions of `0`, `25`, `50`, and `75` at the same time, and if all of them complete after a similar elapsed time, it would be followed by a parallel evaluation of `1`, `26`, `51`, and `76`. If any of the four elements of the first evaluation “wins” and determines the cached data, it will be suitable for only one of the next four values. If the timing of the threads shifts, the ratio will get even worse.

One solution would be to change `doComputationallyIntensiveThing` to use thread local caches, to benefit from the processing of consecutive elements in each thread. Then, the way you have defined the Stream operation, is perfect for this operation which benefits from repeatedly seeing the same element of `arr1`. Though, you can simplify the code and eliminate a lot of the boxing overhead:

```
Arrays.stream(arr1).parallel().forEach(i1 ->
    Arrays.stream(arr2).forEach(i2 ->
        Arrays.stream(arr3).forEach(i3 ->
            doComputationallyIntensiveThing(i1, i2, i3))));
```

However, this creates the challenge of cleaning up the thread-local caches afterwards, as the parallel Stream uses a thread pool outside your control.

A simpler work-around for the way, the method works today, is to change the nesting:

```
Arrays.stream(arr2).parallel().forEach(i2 ->
    Arrays.stream(arr1).forEach(i1 ->
        Arrays.stream(arr3).forEach(i3 ->
            doComputationallyIntensiveThing(i1, i2, i3))));
```

Now, `arr2` gets split the way described above. Then, every worker thread will do the same iteration over `arr1`, processing each element of it as many times as there are elements in `arr3`. This allows to utilize the inter-thread caching behavior, but there is the risk that the threads get out of sync due to timing differences, ending up at the same situation as before.

A much better alternative is to redesign the `doComputationallyIntensiveThing`, creating two different methods, one preparing the operation for a particular element of `arr1` returning an object containing the cached data for the element, and another for the actual processing utilizing the cached data:

```
Arrays.stream(arr1).parallel()
    .mapToObj(i1 -> prepareOperation(i1))
    .forEach(cached ->
        Arrays.stream(arr2).forEach(i2 ->
            Arrays.stream(arr3).forEach(i3 ->
                doComputationallyIntensiveThing(cached, i2, i3))));
```

Here, each instance returned by `prepareOperation` is associated with a particular element of `arr1` and acts as a local cache for any data associated with it, but gets garbage collected normally when the processing of the particular element is over. So there’s no cleanup needed.

In principle, it would also work if `prepareOperation` only returns an empty holder object, to be populated by the first invocation of `doComputationallyIntensiveThing` for the particular element.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's a good explanation and good ideas. It's not what I ended up using though. Preparing the cache before hand doesn't work out so well for me because I don't know before hand exactly what values it needs to be prepopulated with. Also, having one cache per thread didn't make much sense for my application because this cache ends up being nearly as big as my available ram. I ended up decided to just not use streams and went with a more Java-7 style threadpool approach. It was just simpler.

Answer (score 0):

To keep code simple, the below code is for one array (you can extend it to include more arrays).

```
    class IteratorSpliteratorOfDouble implements Spliterator.OfDouble {

        private long m_estimate;
        private final DoubleSupplier m_supplier;

        /**
         * @param supplier -- returns Double.NaN if no more elements
         */
        private IteratorSpliteratorOfDouble(final long size,
                final DoubleSupplier supplier) {
            m_estimate = size;
            m_supplier = supplier;
        }

        public IteratorSpliteratorOfDouble(final double[] array) {
            this(array.length, new DoubleSupplier() {

                int m_idx = 0;

                @Override
                public synchronized double getAsDouble() {
                    if (m_idx >= array.length) {
                        return Double.NaN;
                    }

                    return array[m_idx++];
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public long estimateSize() {
            return m_estimate;
        }

        @Override
        public int characteristics() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(final DoubleConsumer action) {               

            final double next = m_supplier.getAsDouble();
            if (Double.isNaN(next)) {
                return false;
            }

            action.accept(next);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator.OfDouble trySplit() {

            if (m_estimate == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return new IteratorSpliteratorOfDouble(
                    m_estimate = m_estimate >>> 1, m_supplier);
        }
    }
```

an example for using the above is:

```
    final double[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
    StreamSupport.doubleStream(new IteratorSpliteratorOfDouble(arr), true)
            .forEach(idx -> doComputationallyIntensiveThing(idx));
```

The code will keep the array's elements order, while utilizing java parallel.